# Getting invalid host while reindexing in aws opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I've two domains of Elastic search v 7.7, hosted under same VPC. I'm trying to reindex data between two domain by following steps mentioned in aws doc [reindex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/remote-reindex.html#remote-reindex-vpc). But getting below error

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid remote host:[.......]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid remote host:[.....]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Request I'm executing on KIBANA

```
POST _reindex?pretty=true
{
   "source":{
      "remote":{
         "host":"https://endpoint:443",
          "socket_timeout": "60m"
      },
      "index":"uiauto-2018071611"
   },
   "dest":{
      "index":"uiauto-2018071611"
   }
}
```